# WebView without height inside Scroll not working

Tags: flutter, webview

On Flutter...I tried to add Webview inside all the available containers that support scroll but it didn't work on Android.

```
ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
           Expanded(
                child: WebView(
                    key: Key("webview1"),
                    debuggingEnabled:  true,
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/")),
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
            Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
          ],
)
```

Comment: check here: https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2

Comment: I checked this article but it didn't work with me. It seemed that adding Webview on Scroll container is one of the most weakness points on Flutter

Comment: Can u share some compilable code to check?

Comment: i added the ListView code to the description

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to put your scrollable WebView between other widget's and WebView will be scrollable, other's widget's are not, then just change your ListView for Column like that:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    Container(
      height: 300,
      child: WebView(
          key: Key("webview1"),
          debuggingEnabled: true,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/")
    ),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
)
```

But if u want to have some scrollable widgets on top of WebView, then try
[CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) or [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html).

Can you tell what exact logic you are trying to make?

additions:

If you want to have scrollable area and some WebView inside, you can have to know height of WebView:

```
ListView(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 10000),
        child: WebView(
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(
              Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
              ), // or null
            ),
            key: Key("webview1"),
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/")),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
    Text("hiiiiiiiiiiiii "),
  ],
);
```

Height of WebView you could get dynamically, inspiration is here:
https://gist.github.com/PonnamKarthik/877a90917a576ecff613d5169680d02c

Comment: I want to make a full scrollable Widget contains WebView (with dynamic height and no scroll inside it) and other containers above and below it. all should scroll inside the parent Widget.

Comment: WebView widget it's like a browser with a scroll inside it, you can disable scrolling it, I mean inner scroll, but then you have to know the exact height of that Widget, otherwise, it wouldn't work.

Comment: How can i know the height of Webview contains iframes, galleries and videos. On Native Android App, i can put webview inside nestedscrollview without adding height for the webview and it worked well. I know that Webview on Flutter is based on Native Webview so why the scrolling feature not working as the native

Comment: I changed my solution based on your needs. Height of WebView you can get like in this example: https://gist.github.com/PonnamKarthik/877a90917a576ecff613d5169680d02c

Comment: Okay, i will check your solution and feedback you

Comment: Fellow programmers. Try "offsetHeight" too.

"document.documentElement.offsetHeight;" worked for me.

"Not document.body.scrollHeight;" ScrollHeight made it HUGE, offsetHeight made it perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you dubace for your solution gist.github.com/PonnamKarthik/877a90917a576ecff613d5169680d02c

The issue solved and now we can add Webview inside parent scrollable container.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Code Sample',
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget navigator) {
        return MyStatelessWidget();
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatelessWidgetState createState() => _MyStatelessWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget> {
  List<WebViewController> _listController = List();

  List<double> _heights =
      List<double>.generate(htmlStrings.length, (int index) => 20.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: htmlStrings.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: _heights[index] ?? 100.0,
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl:
                  'data:text/html;base64,${base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(htmlStrings[index]))}',
              onPageFinished: (some) async {
                double height = double.parse(await _listController[index]
                    .evaluateJavascript(
                        "document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"));
                setState(() {
                  _heights[index] = height;
                });
              },
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                _listController.add(controller);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

final List<String> htmlStrings = [
  '''<p>Table shows some compounds and the name of their manufacturing process</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 85px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; height: 17px;">Compounds/Elements</td>
<td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; height: 17px;">Manufacture process</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Nitric acid</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Ostwald's process</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Ammonia</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Haber's process</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Sulphuric acid</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Contact process</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Sodium</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 17px;">Down's process</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>''',
  '''<p>\(L=[M{L }^{2 }{T }^{-2 }{A }^{-2 }]\)</p>
<p>\(C=[{M }^{-1 }{L }^{-2 }{T }^{4 }{A }^{2 }]\)</p>
<p>\(R=[M{L }^{2 }{T }^{-3 }{A }^{-2 }]\)</p>
<p>\(\therefore \frac {R}{L}=\frac{[M{L }^{2 }{T }^{-2 }{A }^{-2 }]}{[M{L }^{2 }{T }^{-3 }{A }^{-2 }]}=[T]\)</p>''',
  '''<p>Displacement(s)\(=\left(13.8\pm0.2\right)m\)</p>
<p>Time(t)\(=\left(4.0\pm0.3\right)s\)</p>
<p>Velocity(v)\(=\frac{13.8}{4.0}=3.45m{s}^{-1}\)</p>
<p>\(\frac{\delta v}{v}=\pm\left(\frac{\delta s}{s}+\frac{\delta t}{t}\right)=\pm\left(\frac{0.2}{13.8}+\frac{0.3}{4.0}\right)=\pm0.0895\)</p>
<p>\(\delta v =\pm0.0895*3.45=\pm0.3\)(rounding off to one place of decimal)</p>
<p>\(v=\left(3.45\pm0.3\right)m{s}^{-1}\)</p>''',
  '''<p>The only real numbers satisfying \(x^2=4\) are 2 and -2. But none of them satisfy the final condition, \(x+2=3\). So, there is no real number such that these conditions are met. Hence this is null set.</p>
<p>Note that, for \(x\) to be a memner of \(\{x:p(x),q(x)\}\),&nbsp;<em><strong>both</strong></em> \(p(x)\) and \(q(x)\) should be true.</p>''',
];
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in the beginning. You can specify which gestures get passed
on to the **webView** widget with the **gestureRecognizers** parameter. Bellow code helps to capture the vertical scroll event.

```dart
WebView(
  initialUrl: someUrl,
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
   ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
   () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
)
```

**I found this post also very useful for webview**
[The Power of WebViews in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2)

Answer (score 2):

**First Method :-**

Make a full scrollable Widget contains WebView (with dynamic height) and other containers above and below it. all should scroll inside the parent Widget

be sure flutter package:`webview_flutter: any` are properly install.

1.create `Future` fxn

```
    String hight;
    double webHight =400; //default some value
    Future funcThatMakesAsyncCall() async{
      var result =
             await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.body.scrollHeight'); 
    //here we call javascript for get browser data
             setState(() {
                       hight = result;
                          },);}
```

2.we use `SingleChildScrollView`
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

3.Inside use `Column`

4.finally we use `Conatiner`

inside `Container` we use `WebView`

here `Container` Code

```
               Container(
                height: webHight+20,
                child: WebView(
                initialUrl: widget.url,
                onPageFinished: (webhight)async{
                   await funcThatMakesAsyncCall();
                   setState((){
                      webHight= double.parse(hight);                          
                   });                        
                  },
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  
                  controller = webViewController;

                  },
                ),
              ),
```

**second method :-**

plugin vesion :> `webview_flutter: ^3.0.4`

```
Column(
          children: [            
            Container(
              height: Get.height * 0.1,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            Expanded(
              // height: 200,
              child: WebView(                              
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                  Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                    () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                  ),
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  bscontroller.webcontroller = webViewController;
                },
                initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

when i stuck another time than in same problem and try my old answer but this not work this time for me so, than i figure out another way

and this second answer to same problem